# Best way to delete duplicate records(Row) in oracle table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

We have a `table` in which there are `millions of records`. We have to `delete duplicate records` from the `table`. What is the best way of doing this.

What I thought I will take `distinct record` in another `table` and then `truncate` the `original table.` After that I will `insert` back the original record.

I gave this answer in `interview`, still got rejected. Can anybody suggest better way of handling it.

Comment: Your solution is the best solution if there are lots of duplicates.

Comment: Yes, As mentioned by @GordonLinoff its totally depend on the nature of data/records. e.g In worst case if there are 90% duplicates records in the table then it makes sense to use your solution. There are different ways to achieve the same thing, just google it. Thanks :)

Comment: You could also ask the interviewer what "best" means for him.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica A record is duplicate if all the column have same values for more than one rows. I need to keep only one row remaining  row will be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I usually use:

```
delete from your_table a
where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid) 
                 from your_table b
                 where a.join_column = b.join_column
                );
```

---

Your option isn't that *bad*; it works OK when you want to keep part of table dataset and remove the rest, so it is faster to "save" desired values, truncate table (which is faster than delete operation) and move saved rows back.

It would be easier to *guess* if the interviewer told you what was wrong with your answer.

---

Also, if you're interested, have a look at some more ways to delete duplicates on [OraFAQ site](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ#How_does_one_eliminate_duplicates_rows_from_a_table.3F).

Comment: . . I disagree with "small".  90% of the data might remain and truncating might still be better.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do that is using correlated Queries and ROW_ID , if the table X has huge number of records and you want to delete a few from it.

Comment: Can you give an example pls

Comment: hi @ShrutiSharma, thanks for the question, the answer is already given by the other user, let me re-iterate it once more here , you could follow that,  delete from your_table a
where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)  --  commnets( this is correlated query because this subquery joins to table from the parent query)
                 frorm your_table  
                 where a.join_column = b.join_column
                );

Comment: No. your answer is incorrect. correlated queries should be last option . they take too much time.

Comment: it depends on the situation , anyway I am happy if you already found the best option

Answer (score 1):

Look no further. Chris Saxon has written a great blog [How to Find and Delete Duplicate Rows with SQL](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-find-and-delete-duplicate-rows-with-sql)